# How tab and space affect code size in C

Tags: c, memory, tabs, space, code-size

When working on embedded system, every byte of memory matters, in C/C++ program is there any difference in resulting code size when you use 4 space instead of 1 tab?

Comment: I don't believe so, but there's nothing stopping you from actually trying yourself.

Comment: What do you think yourself? What will your tabs compile into?

Comment: Did you even try to google this?  And no.

Comment: Yes, so make the code as compact as possible, sticking to one-letter variables and no extra spaces, because that will eat up memory like butter.

Comment: @DeiDei And no newlines! I wonder if there is a [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) compiler for embedded systems...

Comment: Space and Tab individually consumes one ASCII character, when replacing 4 space with a tab, i will saving 3 ASCII characters. But does it really have an impact on resulting binary?

Comment: Well, I can think of some sadistic compiler that will count the blanks and inject corresponding amount of junk into your binary.... Let's say it is *implementation defined*.

Comment: preprocessor eliminates whitespace, the compiler won't even see it. If you're talking about developing on an embedded system with a very limited amount of ram ,,, don't do that. Develop on a standard desktop PC and get a cross-compiler (if necessary) for your embedded device.

Comment: actually, now I think I'm wrong. Preprocessor output certainly has whitespace. It must be the compiler that ignores it.

Comment: @DeiDei how do one-letter variables do anything but make the source code unreadable? They, and spaces, have *no effect* on the executable code size (except when it contains debugging info). You don't compile *on the target system* you use a cross-compiler and upload the executable.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that was sarcasm on DeiDei's part.

Comment: @WeatherVane one letter variable names are a core tenant of job security, don't you practice [writing unmaintainable code](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiB5NLUuvbYAhVM02MKHQV5AzIQFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.se.rit.edu%2F~tabeec%2FRIT_441%2FResources_files%2FHow%2520To%2520Write%2520Unmaintainable%2520Code.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2R0WPe64fSquK17xQBrzQj) :)

Comment: @dbush and others, how does sarcasm help beginners?

Comment: Whitespace in the source code has absolutely no effect on the size of the generated binary.  It's only meaningful during translation to separate tokens - whether a token is separated by a single space, tab, or a hundred spaces doesn't affect the generated machine code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

The emitted binary doesn't change based on what spacing you use in your program.

The amount of space the source file takes up does change though. spaces and tabs are each one character, so using 1 tab vs 4 spaces takes up different amounts of memory. It's important to note that this is only for the source file, and during compilation.

Comment: In particular, the standard specifies that whitespace separating tokens ceases to have any significance at phase 7 of [the 8-phase translation model](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2p1).

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the source code itself with spaces or tabs, makes no difference to the executable code size. It is a preference, mine is never to use tab formatting - please [read this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/).

As for program itself, tabs only make a difference when using **string literals**. The control character `'\t'` is one byte in the executable, any spaces will be one or more.

But I prefer to use a field width specifier such as `printf("%4d", i)` to format the output.